# Should I use sp_executesql or EXEC to run a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that needs to call a 2nd SP multiple times. The only thing that changes are the parameters to the 2nd SP. Something like this:

```
 SELECT @P1=5, @P2=5
 EXEC MyProc @P1, @P2

 SELECT @P1=0, @P2=1
 EXEC MyProc @P1, @P2
```

Now if it was dynamic SQL I was running I know sp_executesql would be better than EXEC but since what I'm calling multiple times in actually a SP should I still use sp_executesql or is EXEC like shown above just as good?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EXEC like you have above which is the form `EXEC storedprocname`

`sp_executesql` is better than `EXEC (@sqlstring)` generally where you have dynamic SQL, not a stored proc. So because you're calling a stored proc, the syntax you have is the best way